# Redirect add to cart for affiliate products

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer

In my catalog I have affiliate products that when someone clicks the “Add to Cart” button, they should get forwarded to an external URL. Does anyone have any ideas how I could do that? I am new to Magento.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Overview

This can be done using an [event observer](http://inchoo.net/magento/tracking-magento-add-product-to-cart-action-for-analytic-software-purpose/) in conjunction with [product attribute](http://www.templatemonster.com/help/magento-how-to-create-an-attribute-and-apply-it-to-products.html). For the purposes of this answer, I will assume you can follow the linked guides and find other resources/answers about creating event observers and product attributes.

## Solution

You could create a new product attribute called `external_link` which you will fill in for your products that have external links. Then by observing the `controller_action_predispatch_checkout_cart_add` event, check whether the product has a value for that attribute and redirect the customer if so. Something like this would do the trick:

### etc/config.xml

Under `config/frontend/events`:

```
<controller_action_predispatch_checkout_cart_add>
    <observers>
        <redirectExternalLink>
            <class>My_AffiliateProducts_Model_Observer</class>
            <method>redirectExternalLink</method>
        </redirectExternalLink>
    </observers>
</controller_action_predispatch_checkout_cart_add>
```

### Model/Observer.php

```
class My_AffiliateProducts_Model_Observer
{
    public function redirectExternalLink(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        $productId = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('product', 0);
        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
        // Check for value set on this product for external_link attribute.
        if ($url = $product->getExternalLink()) {
            Mage::app()->getResponse()->setRedirect($url);
            Mage::app()->getResponse()->sendResponse();
            exit;
        }
        return $this;
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you so much sir for your response.... i tried it but i am not able to redirect.. https://www.dropbox.com/s/qpzge60r69t44h4/app.zip?dl=0 here i have attached my code please review it ... i can't find my mistake @fantasticrice

Comment: @MildMilly - Have you confirmed that the extension is set up properly and the observer is firing? Your code did not include the module definition, so I am just curious what debugging steps you have attempted? This method worked fine when I did a proof of concept myself, but I am not going to walk through every detail of creating your extension, there are plenty of other resources that go into detail on this subject.

Comment: thanks a lot sir ... with your guidance only got my results now ... i made some silly mistakes ... thank you so much sir @fantasticrice

Comment: @MildMilly - Glad to hear, well done. Please [mark the answer as accepted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) to help others.