# magento 2 issue with event observer help needed

Tags: magento2, event-observer

i tried to replicate : [Redirect add to cart for affiliate products](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/65377/redirect-add-to-cart-for-affiliate-products)

in magento 2 but it does not work below is my module code

```
Devshree\Affliliate\etc\frontend\events.xml
```

code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
        <event name="controller_action_predispatch_checkout_cart_add">
        <observer name="devshree_affliliate_event_obs" instance="Devshree\Affliliate\Observer\redirectExternalLink" />
    </event>
</config>
```

and 
**Devshree\Affliliate\Model\Observer.php**

code :

```
namespace Devshree\Affliliate\Observer;

use \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class redirectExternalLink implements ObserverInterface {
    public function execute(Observer $observer) {
        $productId = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('product', 0);
        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
        // Check for value set on this product for external_link attribute.
        if ($url = $product->getExternalLink()) {
            Mage::app()->getResponse()->setRedirect($url);
            Mage::app()->getResponse()->sendResponse();
            exit;
        }
        return $this;
    }
}
```

Comment: You've copied a little too much from that Magento 1 snippet: there's no `Mage::app()` in Magento 2. Haven't tried, but I think you can do it by injecting `\Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http` in your observer, and setting the redirect URL in _that_, then exiting.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use "ActionFlag" and set a NO_DISPATCH. Using exit is not `recommended`:

```
<?php
...
use \Magento\Framework\App\ActionFlag;
...
class MyObserver implements ObserverInterface
{
    ...
    protected $actionFlag;
    ...

    public function __construct(
        ...
        ActionFlag $actionFlag
    ) {
        ...
        $this->actionFlag = $actionFlag;
    }

    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        $this->actionFlag->set('', \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action::FLAG_NO_DISPATCH, true);
        $controller->getResponse()->setRedirect(
            $controller->getUrl($myNewUrl)
        );
    }
    ...
```

P.S: Your code is Magento 1 mixed with Magento 2, you should use Magento 2 way.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the following codes for checking the parameter/attribute for checking affiliate program.

```
<?php

namespace Test\Mymodule\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\ActionFlag;

class TestObserver implements ObserverInterface
{
    protected $actionFlag;

    public function __construct(
        ActionFlag $actionFlag
    ) {
        $this->actionFlag = $actionFlag;
    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();
        $productUrl = $currentProduct->getProductUrl()
        $this->actionFlag->set('', \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action::FLAG_NO_DISPATCH, true);
        $controller->getResponse()->setRedirect(
            $controller->getUrl($productUrl)
        );

    }
}
```